# Prove or disprove that S is a subring of M2(Z).

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

[image]Question:

> Let 
>   $
> S = \left\{ \pmatrix{a&a-b\\a-b&b} \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z \right\}.
> $ 
>   Prove or disprove that S is a subring of $M_2(\Bbb Z)$

I think S is a subring of M2(Z). Because S is subset of M2(Z) and S is not an empty set since if we choose a=1, b=2 (we know a and b are integers) then the matrix we got is an element of S. Then there are 2 properties left such as A-B is element of S and AB is element of S for A,B in S. And S is a subring of M2(Z). Is my solution correct?
I am leaving my solution up there.

Comment: Once you add proofs of those two properties you left, it will be a good proof.  Probably for "subring" you will want to show that the identity belongs to $S$.

Comment: Yes, I should choose b=1 too I guess. Thank you!

Comment: @user789 Why don't upvote and accept the useful answers you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution correct, but you have left out proofs that are essential to the answer. In particular, you must show that for any $A,B \in S$, both $A-B$ and $AB$ are elements of $S$.

It is easy enough to show that $A - B \in S$. However, showing that $AB \in S$ is a bit trickier. To do this, the nicest approach is to first show that each element of $S$ can be written in the form 
$$
a M - bM^{-1} = aM - b(M - I),
$$
where $M = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}$. That is, note that
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}^{-1} = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&-1}.
$$
With this approach, it is also helpful to note that $M^2 = M + I$.

---

For the "direct" approach, it is helpful to first note that with the substitution $a' = a-b$ and $b' = b$, we can write
$$
S = \left\{ 
\pmatrix{a' + b' & a'\\ a' & b'} = a'M + b' I : a',b' \in \Bbb Z
\right\}.
$$
From there, it suffices to verify that
$$
(aM + bI)(cM + dI) = (ac + ad + bc)M + (ac + bd)I.
$$

Comment: I don't understand why we need that inverse matrix M. I uploaded my solution. Maybe I couldn't express the proof well by words.

Comment: @mathstudent As I said, what was missing from your initial post was the proof that $A-B \in S$ and $AB \in S$ for $A,B \in S$.  In your written work, you show that these statements hold, so your written work is complete.  My suggestion with the matrix $M$ avoids expanding long expressions on $a,b,a',b'$, as was necessary for your approach.

Comment: okay I got it, thank you so much.