# Subset of a ring $R =M_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For $R =M_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ let $S$ be a subset of $S$ such that
$$
S = 
\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x & x \\ y & y \end{bmatrix} \, \middle| \, x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$

And I need to prove that $S$ is a subring of $R$, could you give me a hint to solve please.

Comment: You need to prove $S$ is a *subring* of $R$? The identity matrix is not an element of $S$; that would seem to be an issue.

Comment: With your notation $S$ is not even a set, but an element of $R$. Try to improve the notation and the question and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Ignoring the problems in the definition:
How do you check that any subset of a ring is a subring? You check that it is closed under subtraction and multiplication, i.e. you need to show that $s_1-s_2 \in S$ and $s_1\cdot s_2\in S$ for $s_1,s_2\in S$. Here minus and multiplication are just the usual minus and multiplication of matrices, as inherited from $R=M_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654056/prove-or-disprove-that-s-is-a-subring-of-m2z) for an example of $S$, which is a subring.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a ring with unity, then a subset $S\subseteq R$ is a subring precisely when the operations of addition and multiplication from $R$ restricted to $S$ induce ring structure on $S$, with the added stipulation that $S$ contains the unity element of $R$. In this way, both $R$ and $S$ are rings with unity. This is the standard definition of a subring when the rings in question have unity. In your example, $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a ring with identity, so immediately we see that $S$ cannot be a subring since it does not contain the identity matrix.

If $R$ does not contain unity, then we drop that requirement and just say that $S\subseteq R$ is a subring when $S$ is a ring under the inherited operations from $R$. This does not mean that a subring of a ring without unity never has a unity element. Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times 2\mathbb{Z}$. There is no unity element of this ring but the subring $\mathbb{Z}\times \{0\}$ contains a unity element.

Comment: It's mostly a question of conventions. Given the text of the exercise, we can infer that the OP's instructor does not impose the existence of a unity. Whether it exists in the bigger ring is irrelevant. So the subset in the question *is* a subring, according to the convention, otherwise the exercise is wrongly stated. *Your* convention may be different, but it's not mandated by law.